# Can't open options menu with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

When I open the VS2010 I cannot open any menu options.

Comment: works fine for me, also use vs2010 and win8 preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously the VS2010 is working accordingly in Windows 8. I´ve not done nothing to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

try to open Visual Studio in Compabilty Mode.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't experience any issue with it so far.

what are the reason behind using visual studio 2010 on windows 8 RP?
visual studio 2012 should be sufficient except that is might still have some bug.

Comment: The project in my workplace is using VS2010. Opening the project in VS2012 will migrate the solution to this version, avoiding to open it in VS2010 again.